# Primitive type wrapper in C++ that is both POD and constructible in an expression?

Tags: c++

I'd like to create a wrapper class for a primitive type in C++ so that I can overload functions and operators for it. However, I would otherwise like it to act exactly like the primitive type. For instance, I would like it to be a POD type, so it can be used in structures accessed by (separately compiled) C code, and be implicitly convertible to/from the primitive type. As a concrete example, I'd like something like [Boost tribool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/tribool.html), but that is a POD with guaranteed `sizeof` of 1. C++03 compatibility is very desirable, but C++11-only might be useful too.

It's pretty easy to get started with something like this:

```
struct tribool_pod {
    unsigned char value; // can be private in C++11
    tribool_pod& operator=(unsigned char v) { value = v; return *this; }
    constexpr operator unsigned char() const { return value; }
    tribool_pod& operator=(bool v) { value = v ? 1 : 0; return *this; }
    constexpr operator bool() const { return value == 1; }
};
```

Note that there are no user-defined constructors, so that so far it is a POD type. However, I hit the first snag when writing the operators:

```
constexpr tribool_pod operator!() const {
    return value == 0 ? <true-value> :
           value == 1 ? <false-value> :
           <indeterminate-value>;
}
```

In this case, what is the best way to create an instance in an expression for things like `<true-value>`? In C++11, I can use `tribool_pod{true}`, but is there any way in C++03? If structs in C++03 can only be initialized in a variable declaration, the only way I can think to write constant expressions for things like `<true-value>` is to refer to a `static const tribool_pod` (which has external linkage). That has the drawback of not being header-only and is likely less efficient than using the primitive type.

A related problem even in C++11 is that I don't have a conversion from `bool` to `tribool_pod`. Obviously, if I add a conversion constructor to `tribool_pod`, it is no longer a POD.

Is there some trick I'm missing, or is this fundamentally impossible? This seems like an unfortunate consequence of C++ constructors being an all or nothing proposition: Constructors are the only implicit conversion function, but if you define any, one is always called, and you're no longer a POD type. (Or in C++11 terms, it has standard layout, but is not trivial(ly constructible)).

Or maybe I'm worrying too much about POD-ness? If I include conversion constructors and a no-op default constructor, what do I lose? Just super-obscure things like `goto` over initialization? I figure I can probably assume standard layout (e.g. no padding at the beginning of the object) with C++03 from real-world compilers, even though the spec doesn't guarantee it.

**Note**: Part of the reason I care about this is because I want the same headers usable from C (with degraded functionality and safety). For example:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
struct tribool_pod { unsigned char value; ... };
#else
typedef unsigned char tribool_pod;
#endif
```

Comment: I've checked again the C++11 Standard and [written an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/323476b33a87731a): You can add non-trivial converting constructors (but no non-trivial copy-constructors) and still have a POD type.

Answer (score 0):

A header-only solution using a block-static special value:

```
Foo Foo::f()
{
    static const Foo special = make_special_foo();   // or "= { 1, 2, 3 };" etc.

    return condition ? value : special;
}
```

Comment: I considered this, but the problem is that `f()` cannot be a C++11 `constexpr`. I suppose the only way to evaluate the impact is to test both approaches with various compilers. It might be better to just call `make_special_foo()`directly though. I could then likely optimize for C++11 or C++03 using macros: use aggregate init and `constexpr` on C++11, and use a constructor function on C++03.

Comment: I thought you wanted a non-C++11 solution? In C++11 you just use the code you already had, `return {}`. You can indeed use conditional compilation to decide between the two.